# Joule expansion

Tags: thermodynamics

How can we reach the 2nd equation from the 1st one?
$$
\eta = \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_V \tag{1}
$$
$$\downarrow$$
$$
\eta= \frac1{C_V}\left(\frac{\beta T}{\kappa}-P\right) \tag{2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Equation 1 is incorrect.  It should be at constant internal energy, and should read:  $$\eta = \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_U \tag{1}$$Eqn. 1 follows from:  $$dU=C_VdT-\left[P-T\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_V\right]dV$$and the identity:  $$dV=\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)dT+\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial P}\right)dP=V(\beta dT-\kappa dP)$$Also, Eqn. 2 should have a minus sign and should read:  $$\eta= -\frac1{C_V}\left(\frac{\beta T}{\kappa}-P\right) \tag{2}$$